# How to change the font size of a ListView widget in .kv

Tags: python, listview, kivy

I have a simple ListView widget, which I pass a list to from my python code. The .kv looks like this:

```
    ListView:
        id: mylistview
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        font_size: self.height/5
```

But the font size doesn't do anything. I guess I need to (somehow) pass the value to the labels within the list, but having used quite a simple way of doing this I can't quite figure out how. Plus, all the examples I find seem to be Android specific?! Can anyone tell me the simplest way of achieving this please?

EDIT:
Ok, so on the basis of the suggested answer, and an awful lot of Googling, I've come up with the below:

```
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<CustomLabel>:
    font_size: 30

<MyPopup>:
    GridLayout:
        ......
            ListView:
                size_hint: .8, .8
                adapter:
                    ListAdapter(data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)], cls = CustomLabel)
```

Everywhere I've looked suggests this is the correct method, but this just gives me "NameError: name 'CustomLabel' is not defined" ??

Answer (score 2):

Afaik [ListView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html) has no such thing as `font_size`, so this does basically nothing at all.

To get what you want you need to set `font_size` for your `Label` inside the widget and to do that the most simple way is to make a custom `Label` for example:

```
#kv
<CustomLabel>:
    font_size: <pass value here>

#python
class CustomLabel(Label): pass
```

or

```
#python
class CustomLabel(Label):
    font_size = <value>
```

**Edit:** Hups, forgot about the adapter thing. So basically you'll end up with custom `Label` if you don't want to convert arguments and it'll be simplier for you.

```
simple_list_adapter = SimpleListAdapter(
data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)],
cls=CustomLabel)

list_view = ListView(adapter=simple_list_adapter)
```

Comment: I don't seem to understand where I can use this simple_list_adapter code. All my layout for this is in .kv and is on a modal popup. If I try and add this code it just tells me that there is no SimpleListAdapter, and there doesn't seem to be one I can import. There's something I'm fundamentally not 'getting' here I think...

Comment: For anyone reading this, this details exactly how I achieved it in the end, and the struggle I am having with text_size now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276305/setting-the-text-size-of-label-class-in-python-code