# Setting the text_size of label class in python code

Tags: python, kivy

I have a ListView widget which is called using the following code:

.kv:

```
    ListView:
        id: myListView
        size_hint_y: 0.5
```

.py:

```
from kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter import SimpleListAdapter
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class CustomLabel(Label):
    font_name = 'fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf'
    font_size = 18
    color = (1, 1, 0.8, 1)
    halign = 'left'
    text_size = self.size # this line doesn't work


myList = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
sla = SimpleListAdapter(data=myList, cls=CustomLabel)
```

I cannot find a way of setting the text size so it takes up the whole of the label widget's dimensions. 'self' doesn't work, and neither does referencing the widget's id, as it tries to parse the code at initial run time, before the widgets are created.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`self` does not exist in the class definition. But you can create a kivy rule:

```
ListView:
    id: myListView
    size_hint_y: 0.5
    text_size: self.size
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added this and also "halign: 'left'", but I still have centred text in my ListView (I'm trying to left align it essentially, I had thought that it wasn't left aligning because of the text_size, but now I'm not so sure). Nothing I do seems to get the items in the ListView to left justify?!